# Secure HTML Files or Secure Folder Which Contain HTML and PHP files in PHP (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, web-config

i have developed a project which uses HTML files (present in a single folder) in a iframe. 
I have created a index.php which required login to access and inside this index.php i use index.html in a iframe. The problem is if the user call directly call index.html then it can directly see index.html. I want to restrict the users to see index.html directly . I have created this project inside wordpress and use IIS as a web server.

Comment: Which version of IIS are you under?

Answer (score 1):

If you are under IIS 7.x, create a web.config file in your folder which you would like to restrict access and type or paste the following into it. It should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <security>
          <requestFiltering>
               <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="false">
                   <add segment="myfoldername" />
               </hiddenSegments>
           </requestFiltering>
       </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Have a look at the following resource for more information :

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/hiddenSegments

Comment: if i call any file from this folder in iframe then this will restrict that file or not

Comment: It will and won't allow you to view the file because it will be requested by the client (I mean the browser). I am not familiar with php but what you can do is to create a handle on your application which requests those files and then gives you back to html. Then you can use this handler to request files.